# How to avoid extra routes from Network Manager?

Tags: networking, networkmanager, ipv6, wpa-supplicant

On my home wireless network, `network-manager` adds extra routes compared to `wpa_supplicant`, which causes IPv6 hosts on the local network to be unreachable. Route table is shown below, note that `network-manager` adds an extra route via `fe80::...:44af` for global IPv6 addresses on the local network (the `2a00:...::/64` block).

How do I configure `network-manager` to not add this additional route?

Any context as to what this route is and what it is for would also be appreciated. My router's web interface lists this as the "IPv6 LAN Link-Local Address" of the router (note there is also an IPv6 WAN Link Local Address", which is identical except it ends in `44ad`).

## Network Manager

```
$ ip -6 route show
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2a00:...::/64 via fe80::...:44af dev wlp4s0 proto ra metric 600 pref medium
2a00:...::/64 dev wlp4s0 proto kernel metric 600 pref medium
fdaa:bbcc:ddee::/64 via fe80::...:44af dev wlp4s0 proto ra metric 600 pref medium
fdaa:bbcc:ddee::/64 dev wlp4s0 proto kernel metric 600 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev wlp4s0 proto kernel metric 600 pref medium
default via fe80::...:44af dev wlp4s0 proto ra metric 600 pref medium
```

## wpa_supplicant

```
$ ip -6 route show
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2a00:...::/64 dev wlp4s0 proto ra metric 302 mtu 1488 pref medium
fdaa:bbcc:ddee::/64 dev wlp4s0 proto ra metric 302 mtu 1488 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev wlp4s0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
default via fe80::...:44af dev wlp4s0 proto ra metric 302 mtu 1488 pref medium
```